# Issue writing an Algorithm with Vectors

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

```
-(void)userShow{
    vector<CGPoint>::iterator it;
    vector<CGPoint>* xp = x.graphPoints;
    vector<CGPoint>* yp = y.graphPoints;
    xVal = new vector<double>();
    yVal = new vector<double>();
    xyVal = new vector<double>();
    xxVal = new vector<double>();
    value = new vector<double>();
    c = new vector<double>();   


    for(it = xp->begin(); it != xp->end(); ++it){
        xVal->push_back(it->y);
        xxVal->push_back(it->x);

    }
    for(it = yp->begin(); it != yp->end(); ++it){
        xyVal->push_back(it->x);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < xVal->size(); i++){
        c = xVal[i];
        while (xyVal[c] < xxVal[i];){
            c++;
            if ((c-1)<=xxVal[i]<=c){
                double value = xp[c-1] + (xp[c] - yp[c-1])*(xxVal[i] - xyVal[c-1])/(xyVal[c] - xyVal[c-1]);
            }
            yVal->push_back(value);
        }
    }

   UserGraph->removeAllData();
   UserGraph->addDataSet(xVal, yVal, [UIColor redColor], 0, false, true, 2);
   UserGraph->updateAll();
}
```

Above is my pseudo code for what I'd like to have happen. I am still having issues understanding vectors. As you can see above with the yVal = "..." theres an issue with binary expressions with `vector<CGPoint>` and `vector<double>`.

what this algorithm is supposed to do is take a drawn line on two graphs `x(t)` and `y(t)` then grabs the `x(t)`'s `y` coords and turned it into a new vector. After that in the second while, it takes the `x(t)`'s `x` coords to compare to the `y(t)` `x` coords to grab `y` coords. When `x(t)`'s x and `y(t)` `x` don't match it needs to do the `yVal` = algorithm.

Can some one help me turn my pseudo code into working code? Cheers

Comment: What does `x.graphPoints` return?

Comment: the points of x(t) on the first graph. @birryree

Comment: Why are you using `new` with `std::vector`? Avoid `new`.

Comment: @John - to be clearer, are the points an array, another vector, or...? From your code it seems like it'd be a `std::vector<CGPoint>*`, but it's pseudocode so yeah.

Comment: If you must use a pointer to vector, then you'd access items with `(*xp)[n]`. However, allocating a vector object dynamically is a very unusual thing to do in the first place.

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating vectors? You could just say `std::vector<double> xVal;` and avoid pointer indirection and possible resource leaks.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, possible leaks? Definite leaks with the above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mysteries in your code, but something like this hopefully gets you started. I removed the use of pointers-to-`vector` and put some comments in line to explain my changes.

```
void userShow() {

    // I assume that x.graphPoints is just some `std::vector<CGPoint>` and you just want to use it locally

    // if x.graphPoints returns an "std::vector<CGPoint> *" (pointer-to-vector), 
    // you should probably modify the class/struct/whatever to just use the vector,
    // not a pointer-to-vector
    vector<CGPoint>& xp = x.graphPoints;

    // ditto for y.graphPoints
    vector<CGPoint>& yp = y.graphPoints;

    // You almost never use pointers to containers, nor allocate them with new - 
    // it's an atypical practice in C++
    /* 
    xVal = new vector<double>();
    yVal = new vector<double>();
    xyVal = new vector<double>();
    */

    // instead just create the vectors on the stack
    std::vector<double> xVal, yVal, xyVal;

    std::vector<CGPoint>::iterator it;

    // These have been changed to not use -> member notation, since we're not
    // using pointers anymore
    for(it = xp.begin(); it != xp.end(); ++it){
        xVal.push_back(it->y);
        xxVal.push_back(it->x); // I have no idea what xxVal is? I think it's xyVal?
        // xyVal.push_back(it->x); // like this?
    }

    // you can iterate through a vector with this type of loop, or
    // use an iterator as above
    for (int i = 0; i < xp.size(); ++i){
        int c = 1;
        while (xyVal[c] < xxVal[i]) {
            ++c;

            // (c-1)<=xxVal[i]<=c; // ??? 

            // I think the previous line means...c gets the value of xyVal[i], and
            // xxVal gets c-1? You'll have to explain this, otherwise it it just a
            // free-standing conditional comparison

            // EDIT: I think I understand what you mean
            // this was a conditional check to do the yVal stuff
            /**
            if ( (c-1) <= xxVal[i] && xxVal[i] <= c) {
                // yVal = xp[c-1] + (xp[c] - yp[c-1])*(xxVal[i]-xyVal[c-1])/(xyVal[c] - xyVal[c-1]);
            } */

            // as mentioned, yVal is a vector, so what do you want?
            yVal = xp[c-1] + (xp[c] - yp[c-1])*(xxVal[i]-xyVal[c-1])/(xyVal[c] - xyVal[c-1]);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This comment is perfect. Thank you @birryree. I am glad you commented everything. Let me see if I can go through this myself on my own code and report back.

Comment: birryree can we open a chatroom together?

Comment: @JohnRiselvato - go ahead - I can't promise I can be of incredible use, but open a chat and invite me. I'm currently working so my response times till be a little slow.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4390/personal-help not exactly sure if i created the room correctly. Nor do i know how to invite... heres the link though.

Answer (score 1):

`yVal = xp[c-1] + ....`

yVal is a point to a vector of doubles (which you almost certainly don't to be using btw) not a value